# Get result of JavaScript async function from AppleScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, applescript

Similar to [Return Javascript variable to AppleScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23224563/return-javascript-variable-to-applescript) , I want to run JavaScript in Safari and return a value to AppleScript. This works:

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell front document
        set myVar to do JavaScript "function foo() {return 5;};result=foo()"
        return myVar
    end
end tell
```

The problem is that the function returning the variable is asynchronous, waiting for the server to respond a few times. This fails:

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell front document
        set myVar to do JavaScript "async function foo() {return 5;};result=foo()"
        return myVar
    end tell
end tell
```

with error `Script Error: The variable myVar is not defined`.

With javascript `async function foo() {return 5;};result=await foo()`, I get the same error.

The reason I want a value from the async function is that I'm automating a reply to messages on a website. One JavaScript function closes existing messages pop-ups, and waits until they all disappear (with `const async_delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));` and an `await`). Another JavaScript function opens the message pop-up I want and waits until it appears. For now, I am using a delay in AppleScript that is long enough. But the time required for JavaScript varies with the initial number of messages: if AppleScript waits too long, another pop-up message may appear in the meantime and the code sends a reply to the wrong person. Hence, it would be cleaner and more robust if I can fetch the result from asynchronous JavaScript.

Can AppleScript fetch variables from async JavaScript?

Comment: Try internet searching your question *"Can AppleScript fetch variables from async JavaScript"*. When I did a link came up where an OP (different site) brings up inserting a delay (say 2 or more seconds, but depends, just needs to be long enough) to give time for the async to return a value.

Comment: "async function foo() {return 5;};result= await foo()" ?

Comment: @BurakAyyildiz With your code, I still get the same error. I edited the question.

Comment: @GetSet I did search and found the thread from StackOverflow in the post. Yes, I considered doing that hack with in AppleScript, but the delay needed for JavaScript is variable: it can be longer if many elements are present, but if it's too long, other unwanted elements may appear. Hence, it would be cleaner and more robust if I can fetch the result from asynchronous JavaScript. I edited the question with that.

Comment: *"but if AppleScript waits too long, other unwanted elements may appear in the page"* ...  What other elements? And is the AppleScript blocking or non-blocking? ... In addition, from the SO post you linked refer to @Jerry Stratton's answer. That may be another issue with having a `return`. He says not to use one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23224563/return-javascript-variable-to-applescript

Comment: @GetSet I'm automating a reply to messages on a website. One JavaScript function closes existing messages pop-ups, and it's asynchronous to wait until they all disappear. Another JavaScript function opens the message pop-up I want, and it's asynchronous to wait until it appears. If the AppleScript wait is high, another pop-up message may appear in the meantime and the code sends a reply to the wrong person. I added that to the question.

Comment: @GetSet I only have a `return` inside the JavaScript function. If I remove it , then the JavaScript global variable is not defined and neither is `myVar`. I get the same error `Script Error: The variable myVar is not defined`. I believe that @JerryStratton was mentioning the `return` of AppleScript, which is indeed not required.

Comment: Would it be possible to invoke the function and set the result to a hidden HTML field? Then in your AppleScript, do a loop to read the value of this hidden form, if missing, wait for 1 second, repeat a couple of times until you get the value you were looking for in that hidden field or if the max number of retries is reached.

Comment: @user3579815 Yes, that's a good idea. If there's no native way to do this, can you please write an answer?