# Return value from JavaScript to AppleScript

Tags: javascript, applescript

I have exactly the same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23224563/return-javascript-variable-to-applescript) but I don't know how to apply that solution to my situation. My JavaScript looks like this:

```
var result = [];
var xpathResult = document.evaluate('" & xpathExpression & "', document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
var node;
while (node = xpathResult.iterateNext()) {
    result.push(node);
}
result;
```

and when I execute it in the browser console it returns a string (or null) but how do I get that string to be returned to my AppleScript?

I have an simpler version of the JavaScript

```
var result = document.evaluate(''" & xpathExpression & "', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
result.singleNodeValue"
```

but it has the same problem - no return value. I can even do an alert() and the string is displayed in the browser but it seems impossible to get the string back to the AppleScript.

Comment: The other question's answer implies that the last global variable gets returned.  So result needs to be declared without var.

Comment: @James Removed all `var` from the code, but it made no difference.

Comment: Removing all `var` from the first sample will definitely not work.  You need to only remove `var` from the declaration of `result`.  The final line, `result;` - doesn't make sense by itself in a javascript sense, try removing that too.